# How to solve a heat equation with homogeneous boundary conditions of the form $u_t = u_{xx} +W(x,t)u$ using the method of variation of parameters?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to solve this problem:
$$u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)+e^{-t}u(x,t),x\in (0,\pi),t>0\\u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,t>0\\u(x,0)=\sin(2x),x\in(0,\pi)$$

but I don't know how to deal with the $e^{-t}$ term. If it was a constant coefficient of $u$, I would substitute: $U = Ve^{ax +bt} $  where $V_t = V_{xx}$ with homogenous boundary conditions.

P.S. (it's my first post here so I am sorry if the question is unclear. Also, this is not a homework question.)

Comment: Why should this question be closed ?

Comment: $u(x,t)=f(T(t))v(x,T(t))$ then pick $f$ and $T$ to simplify the equation

Comment: $$u_{t} - e^{-t} u = u_{xx} \implies (e^{e^{-t}} u)_{t} = (e^{e^{-t}} u)_{xx}$$ so let $e^{e^{-t}} u = v$.

Comment: A friend told me that the equation is considered homogenous after all  , which means that just a simple separation of parameters without any substitution works . I still don't know why that is though.Can someone explain ?

Comment: Yes, I understand now .Thank you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting the ansatz $u(x,t)=f(t)\sin(2x)$ in the PDE $u_t=u_{xx}+e^{-t}u$, we obtain
\begin{align}
f'(t)\sin(2x)&=-4f(t)\sin(2x)+e^{-t}f(t)\sin(2x) \\
&\implies f'(t)=(e^{-t}-4)f(t) \\
&\implies f(t)=C\exp(-e^{-t}-4t), \tag{1}
\end{align}
hence
$$
u(x,t)=C\exp(-e^{-t}-4t)\sin(2x). \tag{2}
$$
This function satisfies the boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$, and the initial condition $u(0,t)=\sin(2x)$ if $C=e$. Therefore, the solution to the problem is given by
$$
u(x,t)=\exp(1-e^{-t}-4t)\sin(2x). \tag{3}
$$